# Checking for duplicates in a series/dict

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following `Series` which is the result of using `Stack` on a `DataFrame` to result in the desired output:

```
col1  col2
A     GS      0.522696
F     GS      0.422812
GS    A       0.522696
      F       0.422812
```

In the above example, the rows `(A,GS) = 0.522696` and `(GS,A) = 0.522696` are considered to be the same so I need to filter out one of them. The same goes for `(F,GS) = 0.422812` and `(GS,F) = 0.422812`.

Essentially what is happening is that every row will be duplicated in the sense that col1 and col2 will be reversed, but the corresponding float value is the same. (ie: GS,F is a duplicate of F,GS). I therefore need to filter out the 'duplicate'. It doesn't matter which one gets filtered out, I just need the result of the above example to only include two rows.

I've tried to change the structure into a dict just to see if it will be easier to work with, ie: `Series.to_dict()`, which results in:

```
{('GS', 'F'): 0.422812, ('A', 'GS'): 0.522696,
('F', 'GS'): 0.422812, ('GS', 'A'): 0.522696}
```

But I still haven't had any luck, regardless of it is in a series or dict.

Comment: To remove duplicate values from a dict, just iterate through its key, value pairs and add them to a new dict only if the value is not already in its values.  For code to do this see answer by Andrew Cox in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749158/removing-duplicates-from-dictionary.

Comment: You may use new_dict = {v: k for k,v in dict.items()}

Comment: Duplicated pairs can be avoid at first place if you select correlation coefficients only from the upper or lower tri matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use dictionary comprehension to avoid value repetition:

```
new_dict = {v: k for k,v in old_dict.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delete duplicates in the dict:

```
result_dict = Series.to_dict()
for elem in Series:
    if elem in result_dict:
        s_elem1, s_elem0 = elem
        del result_dict[(s_elem0, s_elem1)]
```