# Remove duplicate pandas data frames from dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, duplicates

I have a dictionary containing pandas data frames that have the same column names, and I'd like to remove duplicate data frames with identical values and row ids.

Let's assume this is my dictionary of data frames:

```
>>> dd[0]
              Origin           Destination                Time
0           New York                Boston 2016-03-28 02:00:00
1           New York           Los Angeles 2016-03-28 04:00:00
2             Boston           Los Angeles 2016-03-28 06:00:00
>>> dd[1]
              Origin           Destination                Time
0           New York                Boston 2016-03-28 02:00:00
1           New York           Los Angeles 2016-03-28 04:00:00
2             Boston           Los Angeles 2016-03-28 06:00:00
>>> dd[2]
              Origin           Destination                Time
0           New York                Boston 2016-03-28 02:00:00
1           New York           Los Angeles 2016-03-28 04:00:00
2             Boston           Los Angeles 2016-03-28 06:00:00
>>> dd[3]
              Origin           Destination                Time
1           New York           Los Angeles 2016-03-28 04:00:00
2           Los Angeles             Boston 2016-03-28 06:00:00
3             Boston              New York 2016-03-28 08:00:00
>>> dd[4]
              Origin           Destination                Time
1           New York           Los Angeles 2016-03-28 04:00:00
2           Los Angeles             Boston 2016-03-28 06:00:00
3             Boston              New York 2016-03-28 08:00:00
>>> dd[5]
              Origin           Destination                Time
3             Boston              New York 2016-03-28 08:00:00
4           New York           Los Angeles 2016-03-28 12:00:00
>>> dd[6]
              Origin           Destination                Time
3             Boston              New York 2016-03-28 08:00:00
4           New York           Los Angeles 2016-03-28 12:00:00
```

I want the result to look like this:

```
>>> dd[0]
              Origin           Destination                Time
0           New York                Boston 2016-03-28 02:00:00
1           New York           Los Angeles 2016-03-28 04:00:00
2             Boston           Los Angeles 2016-03-28 06:00:00
>>> dd[3]
              Origin           Destination                Time
1           New York           Los Angeles 2016-03-28 04:00:00
2           Los Angeles             Boston 2016-03-28 06:00:00
3             Boston              New York 2016-03-28 08:00:00
>>> dd[5]
              Origin           Destination                Time
3             Boston              New York 2016-03-28 08:00:00
4           New York           Los Angeles 2016-03-28 12:00:00
```

This is my code leading up to this above-mentioned example:

```
# Load data as pandas data frame
data = pd.read_csv("website.txt", names = ["Time", "Origin", `"Destination"])`
data["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(data["Time"], infer_datetime_format=True)
# Reverse data frame by index to loop backwards
data = data.reindex(index=df.index[::-1]) 
dd = {} 
for i, e in reverse.iterrows(): 
    dd[i] = data[ (data['Time'] > e['Time']-pd.Timedelta('4 hours')) & (data['Time'] < e['Time'] + pd.Timedelta('4 hours'))]
```

Original Text:

```
{"Time": "2016-03-28T02:00:00Z", "Origin": "New York", "Destination": "Boston"}
{"Time": "2016-03-28T02:00:00Z", "Origin": "New York", "Destination": "Boston"}
{"Time": "2016-03-28T02:00:00Z", "Origin": "New York", "Destination": "Boston"}
{"Time": "2016-03-28T04:00:00Z", "Origin": "New York", "Destination": "Los Angeles"}
{"Time": "2016-03-28T04:00:00Z", "Origin": "New York", "Destination": "Los Angeles"}
{"Time": "2016-03-28T04:00:00Z", "Origin": "New York", "Destination": "Los Angeles"}
{"Time": "2016-03-28T06:00:00Z", "Origin": "Boston", "Destination": "Los Angeles"}
{"Time": "2016-03-28T06:00:00Z", "Origin": "Boston", "Destination": "Los Angeles"}
{"Time": "2016-03-28T06:00:00Z", "Origin": "Boston", "Destination": "Los Angeles"}
{"Time": "2016-03-28T08:00:00Z", "Origin": "Boston", "Destination": "New York"}
{"Time": "2016-03-28T08:00:00Z", "Origin": "Boston", "Destination": "New York"}
{"Time": "2016-03-28T12:00:00Z", "Origin": "New York", "Destination": "Los Angeles"}
{"Time": "2016-03-28T12:00:00Z", "Origin": "New York", "Destination": "Los Angeles"}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing Duplicates From Dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749158/removing-duplicates-from-dictionary)

Comment: it is convention to use 'pd' as short for pandas "import pandas as pd" convention for 'df' is short for dataframe. Your code if confusing to read vs pandas/python conventions.

Comment: Hey Merlin, I had long noticed your comments  below. Please give me time to make adjustments.

Comment: @Merlin Hey Merlin, I was wondering if you could suggest a way to bridge this question with the other question I had asked and you had answered. Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: @Provisional.Modulation what do you mean bridge?

Comment: @Merlin After looping through the master dataset using the criteria of 4 hours to obtain the subsets, delete the data frames that are duplicates.

Comment: @Provisional.Modulation  piRSquared has done alot work here, why cant you combine?

Comment: The issue is that the reduced dictionary contains data frames that have `NaN` values. I'm still a Python novice, so I can't fully understand what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### One liner

```
{k: v.unstack() for k, v in pd.DataFrame({k: v.stack() for k, v in dd.iteritems()}).T.drop_duplicates().iterrows()}
```

#### Explained version

```
# iterate through key, value pairs of dictionary,
# stacking each dataframe into a series so that we
# can pass the resulting dataframe into the pd.DataFrame constructor.
df1 = pd.DataFrame({k: v.stack() for k, v in dd.iteritems()})
# Each column is now one key, value pair from the original dictionary
# Transpose and drop duplicates
df2 = df1.T.drop_duplicates()
# reverse the original stacking and convert back to dictionary
# we could have used df2.T.iteritems() but df2.iterrows() took
# one fewer operations and fewer characters to type.
dd_ = {k: v.unstack() for k, v in df2.iterrows()}

for k, v in dd_.iteritems():
    print 'key {}:'.format(k)
    print v
    print '-' * 10

key 0:
   a  b
0  1  2
1  3  4
----------
key 2:
   a  b
0  2  3
1  4  5
----------
```

---

#### Setup to get same results as me (copy and paste this)

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd

text0 = """              Origin           Destination                 Time
0           New York                Boston  2016-03-28 02:00:00
1           New York           Los Angeles  2016-03-28 04:00:00
2             Boston           Los Angeles  2016-03-28 06:00:00"""


text1 = """              Origin           Destination                 Time
0           New York                Boston  2016-03-28 02:00:00
1           New York           Los Angeles  2016-03-28 04:00:00
2             Boston           Los Angeles  2016-03-28 06:00:00"""

text2 = """              Origin           Destination                 Time
0           New York                Boston  2016-03-28 02:00:00
1           New York           Los Angeles  2016-03-28 04:00:00
2           Los Angeles             Boston  2016-03-28 06:00:00"""

dd = {}

dd[0] = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text0), sep='\s{2,}', index_col=0, engine='python')
dd[0].Time = pd.to_datetime(dd[0].Time)

dd[1] = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text1), sep='\s{2,}', index_col=0, engine='python')
dd[1].Time = pd.to_datetime(dd[1].Time)

dd[2] = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text2), sep='\s{2,}', index_col=0, engine='python')
dd[2].Time = pd.to_datetime(dd[2].Time)

# Then run solutions above:

df1 = pd.DataFrame({k: v.stack() for k, v in dd.iteritems()})
df2 = df1.T.drop_duplicates()
dd_ = {k: v.unstack() for k, v in df2.iterrows()}

for k, v in dd_.iteritems():
    print 'key {}:'.format(k)
    print v
    print '-' * 10
```

You should get this:

```
key 0:
     Origin  Destination                 Time
0  New York       Boston  2016-03-28 02:00:00
1  New York  Los Angeles  2016-03-28 04:00:00
2    Boston  Los Angeles  2016-03-28 06:00:00
----------
key 2:
        Origin  Destination                 Time
0     New York       Boston  2016-03-28 02:00:00
1     New York  Los Angeles  2016-03-28 04:00:00
2  Los Angeles       Boston  2016-03-28 06:00:00
----------
```

---

#### Version

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
print sys.version
print pd.__version__

2.7.11 |Anaconda custom (x86_64)| (default, Dec  6 2015, 18:57:58) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)]
0.18.1
```

Comment: @piRSquared: Dict arent keys sorted, will this return reproducible resutls...was working on sorting keys then test for dups to get reproducible results. OP looks wants first key of dup.

Comment: @Provisional.Modulation What do you mean "multiple types of duplicate data frames"?  This uses `pd.DataFrame.drop_duplicates()` method, which accomodates the `keep` parameter.  `keep` can be set to `first` in which the first seen is kept and all else are dropped.  or `last` in which the last seen is kept and all else are dropped.  Or, `False` in which if it was duplicated, it gets dropped.

Comment: OP using df for dicts is bad form. unpythonic

Comment: I changed 'df' to 'dd in question, confusing!

Comment: @Provisional.Modulation you are referencing `'website.txt'` that I don't have access to.  Please include the raw text.

Comment: Done. To clarify, what I mean by duplicate data frames are those with the same rows and columns of information.