# How to compare components versions and find the latest ones in python list of dict?

Tags: python

I have a simple list of components dict to install.

```
components = [
    {"component1": "0.1"},
    {"component2": "0.2"},
    {"component1": "0.3"},
    {"component1": "0.2"},
    {"component2": "1.0"}
]
```

Components may be the same, but have different versions. I want to get a list of components with **latest** versions. So, expecting result is

```
latest_components = [
    {"component1": "0.3"},
    {"component2": "1.0"}
]
```

What is the best way to compare component to each other? I tried to solve it using bash, but it looks like crap, so I want to make it more readable using python.

Comment: Try using this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40985281/python-comparing-values-in-the-same-dictionary or just try by availing the for loops and play with it would help you out.

Comment: If you have `pandas` installed: `[{k:v} for k,v in pd.DataFrame(components,dtype=float).max().to_dict().items()]`.

Comment: @HenryYik thanks! But it has to be small builtin script without dependencies...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One line. Works with multilevel versions (1.2.4.7...)

```
{c:'.'.join(map(str,v)) for c,v in sorted([c,list(map(int, v.split('.')))] for l in components for c,v in l.items())}
```

Comment: your solution works well for a case when component has more than 2 digits, like 0.1.3.0
thanks

Comment: @approximatenumberI did not think about comparing versions with multiple digits (for .9 and .11). Now it is ok

Answer (score 1):

An example of achieving this might be:

```
components = [
    {"component1": "0.1"},
    {"component2": "0.2"},
    {"component1": "0.3"},
    {"component1": "0.2"},
    {"component2": "1.0"}
]
result = dict()
for d in components:
    for key, value in d.items():
        if key in result:
            if float(result[key])<float(value):
                result[key]=value
            else:
                continue
        else:
            result[key] = value
print(result)
```

the output for this is:

```
{'component1': '0.3', 'component2': '1.0'}
```