# How can I delete a repeated dictionary in list?

Tags: python

for dynamic values sometimes the value will be keep repeating, say if a variable

```
table = [
    {'man':'tim','age':'2','h':'5','w':'40'},
    {'man':'jim','age':'4','h':'3','w':'20'},
    {'man':'jon','age':'24','h':'5','w':'80'}, 
    {'man':'tim','age':'2','h':'5','w':'40'},
    {'man':'tto','age':'7','h':'4','w':'49'}    
]
```

here `{'man':'tim','age':'2','h':'5','w':'40'}` dictionary set repeat twice these are dynamic value.

How can I stop repeating this, so list will not contain any repeated dictionary before rendering it to templates?

edited: actual data

```
[{'scorecardid': 1, 'progress2': 'preview', 'series2': 'Afghanistan v Zimbabwe in UAE, 2018', 'Commentary1': '/Commentary1', 'commentaryid': 1, 'matchid2': '10', 'matchno2': '5th ODI', 'teams2': 'AFG vs ZIM', 'matchtype2': 'ODI', 'Scorecard1': '/Scorecard1', 'status2': 'Starts on Feb 19 at 10:30 GMT'}, {'six2': '0', 'scorecardid': 2, 'overs5': '4', 'fours1': '0', 'overs10': '20', 'Batting_team_img': 'images/RSA.png', 'wickets20': '5', 'wickets6': '1', 'Bowling_team_img': 'images/IND.png', 'maidens6': '0', 'Batting team': 'RSA', 'matchid2': '9', 'name6': 'Unadkat', 'teams2': 'RSA vs IND', 'wickets10': '9', 'desc10': 'Inns', 'runs5': '32', 'matchtype2': 'T20', 'Scorecard1': '/Scorecard2', 'runs1': '2', 'wickets5': '0', 'runs6': '33', 'runs2': '0', 'maidens5': '0', 'runs20': '203', 'name5': 'Bumrah*', 'progress2': 'complete', 'Commentary1': '/Commentary2', 'fours2': '0', 'series2': 'India tour of South Africa, 2017-18', 'name1': 'Junior Dala*', 'commentaryid': 2, 'matchno2': '1st T20I', 'six1': '0', 'overs6': '4', 'Bowling team': 'IND', 'balls2': '2', 'balls1': '3', 'name2': 'Shamsi', 'overs20': '20', 'runs10': '175', 'desc20': 'Inns', 'status2': 'Ind won by 28 runs'}, {'scorecardid': 3, 'overs5': '0.4', 'fours1': '0', 'overs10': '18.4', 'Batting_team_img': 'images/BAN.png', 'wickets20': '4', 'wickets6': '1', 'Bowling_team_img': 'images/SL.png', 'Batting team': 'BAN', 'matchid2': '6', 'name6': 'Shanaka', 'teams2': 'BAN vs SL', 'wickets10': '10', 'desc10': 'Inns', 'runs5': '3', 'matchtype2': 'T20', 'Scorecard1': '/Scorecard3', 'runs1': '1', 'wickets5': '2', 'runs6': '5', 'maidens5': '0', 'runs20': '210', 'progress2': 'complete', 'Commentary1': '/Commentary3', 'name5': 'Gunathilaka*', 'series2': 'Sri Lanka tour of Bangladesh, 2018', 'name1': 'Nazmul Islam', 'commentaryid': 3, 'matchno2': '2nd T20I', 'six1': '0', 'overs6': '1.5', 'Bowling team': 'SL', 'maidens6': '0', 'balls1': '1', 'overs20': '20', 'runs10': '135', 'desc20': 'Inns', 'status2': 'SL won by 75 runs'}, {'six2': '2', 'scorecardid': 4, 'overs5': '4', 'fours1': '1', 'overs10': '20', 'Batting_team_img': 'images/NZ.png', 'wickets20': '7', 'wickets6': '1', 'Bowling_team_img': 'images/ENG.png', 'maidens6': '0', 'Batting team': 'NZ', 'matchid2': '4', 'name6': 'Tom Curran', 'teams2': 'NZ vs ENG', 'wickets10': '4', 'desc10': 'Inns', 'runs5': '41', 'matchtype2': 'T20', 'Scorecard1': '/Scorecard4', 'runs1': '7', 'wickets5': '0', 'runs6': '32', 'runs2': '37', 'maidens5': '0', 'runs20': '194', 'name5': 'Chris Jordan*', 'progress2': 'complete', 'Commentary1': '/Commentary4', 'fours2': '2', 'series2': 'England, Australia, New Zealand T20I Tri-Series, 2018', 'name1': 'de Grandhomme*', 'commentaryid': 4, 'matchno2': '6th Match', 'six1': '0', 'overs6': '3', 'Bowling team': 'ENG', 'balls2': '30', 'balls1': '5', 'name2': 'Chapman', 'overs20': '20', 'runs10': '192', 'desc20': 'Inns', 'status2': 'Eng won by 2 runs'}, {'scorecardid': 5, 'overs5': '7.4', 'fours1': '3', 'runs20': '213', 'six2': '0', 'commentaryid': 5, 'Batting team': 'SAUS', 'matchid2': '18770', 'matchno2': '21st Match', 'wickets10': '3', 'overs10': '49.4', 'matchtype2': 'TEST', 'runs1': '26', 'overs6': '8', 'runs6': '39', 'runs2': '49', 'name1': 'Mennie*', 'name5': 'Daniel Fallins*', 'series2': 'Sheffield Shield, 2017-18', 'Commentary1': '/Commentary5', 'wickets6': '1', 'runs11': '281', 'six1': '0', 'runs10': '192', 'balls1': '58', 'overs11': '74.1', 'maidens5': '1', 'desc21': '1st Inns', 'status2': 'South Aus won by 7 wkts', 'runs5': '51', 'wickets11': '10', 'desc11': '1st Inns', 'desc20': '2nd Inns', 'wickets20': '10', 'wickets21': '10', 'teams2': 'NSW vs SAUS', 'balls2': '85', 'Scorecard1': '/Scorecard5', 'wickets5': '1', 'progress2': 'Result', 'runs21': '256', 'fours2': '6', 'desc10': '2nd Inns', 'name6': 'Stobo', 'maidens6': '1', 'Bowling team': 'NSW', 'name2': 'Ferguson', 'overs20': '68.4', 'overs21': '90.4'}, {'six2': '0', 'scorecardid': 6, 'overs5': '4', 'fours1': '0', 'overs10': '20', 'Batting_team_img': 'images/RSA.png', 'wickets20': '5', 'wickets6': '1', 'Bowling_team_img': 'images/IND.png', 'maidens6': '0', 'Batting team': 'RSA', 'matchid2': '19166', 'name6': 'Unadkat', 'teams2': 'RSA vs IND', 'wickets10': '9', 'desc10': 'Inns', 'runs5': '32', 'matchtype2': 'T20', 'Scorecard1': '/Scorecard6', 'runs1': '2', 'wickets5': '0', 'runs6': '33', 'runs2': '0', 'maidens5': '0', 'runs20': '203', 'name5': 'Bumrah*', 'progress2': 'Result', 'Commentary1': '/Commentary6', 'fours2': '0', 'series2': 'India tour of South Africa, 2017-18', 'name1': 'Junior Dala*', 'commentaryid': 6, 'matchno2': '1st T20I', 'six1': '0', 'overs6': '4', 'Bowling team': 'IND', 'balls2': '2', 'balls1': '3', 'name2': 'Shamsi', 'overs20': '20', 'runs10': '175', 'desc20': 'Inns', 'status2': 'Ind won by 28 runs'}]
```

Comment: Does order matter?

Comment: yeah first priority will be recent value, recent value will be first set

Comment: What have you tried? Have you seen [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749158/removing-duplicates-from-dictionary) or [this site](https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/dictionary/python-data-type-dictionary-exercise-17.php)? Just Googling around....

Comment: @damores, that is not a duplicate since it already had a unique element.

Comment: You are correct. Although the latest edit showing the data kind of hints at the data having an id. Maybe OP @steve can confirm if each dictionary has a unique id?

Comment: no they don't have any unique ID that occurs in a order @damores

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your records do not appear to have a unique identifier to differentiate records, you will need to hash on all key-value pairs. This approach will work as long as you do not have nested mutable objects inside your dictionaries.

I'll use an `OrderedDict` here to maintain order.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
list(
     map(
         dict, 
         OrderedDict.fromkeys(
             map(frozenset, map(dict.items, table)), None
         )
     )
)

[{'age': '2', 'h': '5', 'man': 'tim', 'w': '40'},
 {'age': '4', 'h': '3', 'man': 'jim', 'w': '20'},
 {'age': '24', 'h': '5', 'man': 'jon', 'w': '80'},
 {'age': '7', 'h': '4', 'man': 'tto', 'w': '49'}]
```

Here's what's going on:

1. Convert each dictionary to a `frozenset` of `tuple`s. `frozenset`s are hashable.
2. Hash each `frozenset` as a key into an `OrderedDict`. Duplicates are removed automatically.
3. Retrieve keys and convert back into a list of dictionaries.

There are many ways to reproduce the algorithm described above. I've used the functional programming tool - `map` - which python offers.

Comment: It doesn't seems to work for me, I have put actual data please check the question

Comment: @coldspeed I'm getting this error  descriptor 'items' requires a 'dict' object but received a 'str'

Comment: @steve Aha... is that JSON? You will need to do this first: `import json; tables = json.loads(tables)`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ JSON uses `"`, not `'`.

Comment: @coldspeed table = json.loads(table)
   list(map(dict, OrderedDict.fromkeys(map(frozenset, map(dict.items, table)), None).keys()))
   gamest.append(table)
   print(gamest)

TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'dict'

Comment: That `.keys()` isn't needed, is it?

Comment: I don't know what your problem is, one comment says something and another comment says something else :/

Comment: @coldspeed sorry for mis-confusion before I didn't assign the result back so I got that error, now I'm getting  error TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'dict'

Comment: @steve So is it a string or a dictionary or a list of strings or a list of dictionaries?!

Comment: @coldspeed it contains strings too I didn't see that {'Commentary1': '/Commentary1', 'matchtype2': 'ODI', 'matchno2': '5th ODI', 'commentaryid': 1, 'status2': 'Starts on Feb 19 at 10:30 GMT', 'teams2': 'AFG vs ZIM', 'scorecardid': 1, 'series2': 'Afghanistan v Zimbabwe in UAE, 2018', 'progress2': 'preview', 'matchid2': '10', 'Scorecard1': '/Scorecard1'}

Comment: 'scorecardid': 1 which is a string

Comment: @steve Yes, but that looks like a key in a dictionary, so that's okay. Do your list items also have strings...?

Comment: @coldspeed I don't see one, but all those dictionary are not unique I have one different set {'teams2': 'AFG vs ZIM', 'scorecardid': 1, 'status2': 'Starts on Feb 19 at 10:30 GMT', 'Scorecard1': '/Scorecard1', 'series2': 'Afghanistan v Zimbabwe in UAE, 2018', 'Commentary1': '/Commentary1', 'progress2': 'preview', 'matchno2': '5th ODI', 'matchtype2': 'ODI', 'matchid2': '10', 'commentaryid': 1}

Comment: followed by similar set {'Batting team': 'RSA', 'scorecardid': 2, 'Commentary1': '/Commentary2', 'name1': 'Junior Dala*', 'runs10': '175', 'status2': 'Ind won by 28 runs', 'overs10': '20', 'runs20': '203', 'series2': 'India tour of South Africa, 2017-18', 'six1': '0', 'balls2': '2', 'overs6': '4', 'overs20': '20', 'Bowling team': 'IND', 'maidens6': '0', 'wickets20': '5', 'fours2': '0', 'progress2': 'complete', 'wickets6': '1', 'matchno2': '1st T20I', 'runs2': '0', 'matchid2': '9', 'runs5': '32', 'wickets5': '0', 'Batting_team_img': 'images/RSA.png', 'teams2': 'RSA vs IND',

Comment: .....'Bowling_team_img': 'images/IND.png', 'runs1': '2', 'Scorecard1': '/Scorecard2', 'name6': 'Unadkat', 'overs5': '4', 'runs6': '33', 'balls1': '3', 'name2': 'Shamsi', 'desc20': 'Inns', 'six2': '0', 'desc10': 'Inns', 'maidens5': '0', 'name5': 'Bumrah*', 'fours1': '0', 'matchtype2': 'T20', 'commentaryid': 2, 'wickets10': '9'}, Does It make any changes?

Comment: @steve If your input was a list of only dictionaries with the EXACT same keys, then this should work :)

Answer (score 2):

You can find and remove the dupes if you can hash them into a set.  One way to do that:

#### Code:

```
def remove_dupes(a_list):
    already_have = set()
    new_table = []
    for row in a_list:
        row_hashable = tuple(sorted(row.items()))
        if row_hashable not in already_have:
            new_table.append(row)
            already_have.add(row_hashable)
    return new_table
```

#### Test Code:

```
table = [
    {'man': 'tim', 'age': '2', 'h': '5', 'w': '40'},
    {'man': 'jim', 'age': '4', 'h': '3', 'w': '20'},
    {'man': 'jon', 'age': '24', 'h': '5', 'w': '80'},
    {'man': 'tim', 'age': '2', 'h': '5', 'w': '40'},
    {'man': 'tto', 'age': '7', 'h': '4', 'w': '49'}
]

print(remove_dupes(table))
```

#### Results:

```
[    
    {'man': 'tim', 'age': '2', 'h': '5', 'w': '40'}, 
    {'man': 'jim', 'age': '4', 'h': '3', 'w': '20'}, 
    {'man': 'jon', 'age': '24', 'h': '5', 'w': '80'},
    {'man': 'tto', 'age': '7', 'h': '4', 'w': '49'}
]
```

Comment: thanks @stephen rauch for answering this doesn't work for my actual data, see the question, I get error saying AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: @steve, so I answered your question.  Then you changed your question?  Why?  Where does that sort of merry-go-round end?  You may enjoy this sort of game where the target is constantly moving.  But I do not.  Decide on your question, then ask.  Please don't waste answer's time by changing your mid.

Comment: sorry for that , first I thought I can explain the question using simple data but it didn't seem to work so I posted actual data, I changed only a data but not the question.

Answer (score 2):

```
list(map(dict, {tuple(sorted(t.items())):1 for t in table}.keys()))
```

or, using sets:

```
list(map(dict, set(tuple(sorted(t.items())) for t in table)))
```

Above solutions do not maintain order in Python < 3.6 as pointed out by @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ.

Below is a solution that will maintain order:

```
singlev = []
for k, v in enumerate([tuple(sorted(t.items())) for t in table]):
    if v not in singlev:
        singlev.append(table[k])
```

Comment: (This won't maintain order unless 3.6.)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Is that a requirement? Did I miss something?

Comment: Yeah, I think so, based on a [clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48858683/how-can-i-delete-a-repeated-dictionary-in-list/48858708?noredirect=1#comment84720800_48858683) to my comment.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ That comment should get into the OP as it is important

Comment: Nah, I think you can keep your answer :)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Could you, please check the last version?

Comment: It certainly works, so +1. I can forgive the linearity of the `in` check, this is a tough problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since your values are all hashable, you can convert to a set of "tuples of tuples", remove duplicates in order, and then convert back to dictionaries.

```
def uniqifier(seq):
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    return (x for x in seq if not (x in seen or seen_add(x)))

[dict(i) for i in uniqifier(tuple(i.items()) for i in table)]
```

The `uniquifier` function is courtesy of [@MarkusJarderot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/480227/9209546). The only modification I made is to use it to return a generator rather than a list.