# Python - Get first value from dictionary with matching keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
d= {'Time': '1', 'Key':'val1'}
d1={'Time':'2', 'Key':'val1'}
d2={'Time':'3', 'Key':'val1'}
d3={'Time':'3', 'Key':'val2'}
d3={'Time':'8', 'Key':'val2'}}
```

How to print the output in this format:

```
output=[{Time': '1', 'Key':'val1'}, {'Time':'3', 'Key':'val2'}]
```

How do I remove the duplicate values by a single key, value combination and print the first occurrence of the combination. Thanks for you help.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749158/removing-duplicates-from-dictionary) out

Answer (score 0):

```
lst =  [
    {'Time': '1', 'Key':'val1'},
    {'Time':'2', 'Key':'val1'},
    {'Time':'3', 'Key':'val1'},
    {'Time':'3', 'Key':'val2'},
    {'Time':'8', 'Key':'val2'}
]
```

Using a `for` loop with `any`

```
res = []
for i in lst:
    if not any(i['Key'] in x.values() for x in res):
        res.append(i)
    else:
        pass

print(res)
# [{'Time': '1', 'Key': 'val1'}, {'Time': '3', 'Key': 'val2'}]
```

Can be done with `itertools.groupby`

```
res = []
for _, g in groupby(lst, key = lambda x: x['Key']):
    res.append(list(g)[0])
```

`itertools.groupby` with list comprehension and `operator.itemgetter`

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

res = [list(g)[0] for _, g in groupby(lst, key=itemgetter('Key'))]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also collect items in a dictionary as you [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) and only add if the key isn't present:

```
from functools import reduce

lst =  [
    {'Time': '1', 'Key':'val1'},
    {'Time':'2', 'Key':'val1'},
    {'Time':'3', 'Key':'val1'},
    {'Time':'3', 'Key':'val2'},
    {'Time':'8', 'Key':'val2'}
]

def collect_if_absent(acc, d):
    if d['Key'] not in acc:
        acc[d['Key']] = d
    return acc

res = list(reduce(collect_if_absent, lst, {}).values())
print(res)
# [{'Time': '1', 'Key': 'val1'}, {'Time': '3', 'Key': 'val2'}]
```

This should take *O(n)*.