# Python: Remove one of two JSON elements if they have the same text

Tags: python, json

How can I remove a JSON element if there's already one with the same text?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you share your code sample so people at SO can assist you better?

Comment: How JSON looks like? Have you converted into something? Would you mind posting your attempt here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume what you are trying to achieve is to remove JSON entries with duplicate values.

Note that in Python, a JSON element is the same as a dictionary. You can therefore just iterate through the dictionary and create a new dictionary which doesn't contain duplicates like so:

```
result = {}

for key,value in input_raw.items():
    if value not in result.values():
        result[key] = value

print(result)
```

Taken from [Removing Duplicates From Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749158/removing-duplicates-from-dictionary). See that link for more information/alternate solutions.

For the input:

```
{
  'key1':'a',
  'key2':'b',
  'key3':'b',
  'key4':'c'
}
```

this successfully produces the ouptput:

```
{
  'key1':'a',
  'key2':'b',
  'key4':'c'
}
```

Comment: What if the values are nested?

Comment: @Idlehands what do you mean when they are nested? Could you give some example input.

Comment: @Idlehands `{1:{1:'b'}, 2:{1:'b'}}` shall result in `{1:{1:'b'}}` with this code, but `{1:{1:'b'}, 2:{1:'c'}}` will result in an identical dictionary. That is the expected behaviour, if I am understanding the question right.

Comment: What I'm saying is the question is unclear, your answer has certain assumptions that should be clarified by the question.  If the `json` is `{1: 'b', 2: {3: 'b'}}` what happens then? These are clarifications required of the question.

Comment: You're right. In my answer, I am assuming OP wants to remove duplicates of values that are equal to each other. Some clarification is needed.