# How to delete values of a dictionary of lists

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, indexing

How do I delete a specific element of each dictionary item?

Given the following example, I want to delete **2nd** element in `key1`, `key2` and `key3`.

```
data{'key1':[value1 ,"abc" ,value3, value4]
     'key2':[value1 ,"def" ,value3, value4]
     'key3':[value1 ,1 ,value3, value4]}
```

So it should become:

```
Input: 2
Output: 
data{'key1':[value1,value3,value4]
     'key2':[value1,value3,value4]
     'key3':[value1,value3,value4]}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific ?

Comment: Hi, nputin! Welcome to the community. We are more than happy to see you here, all set to contribute for the first time. Your question seems a bit confusing, what is it that you want to delete in that dictionary?

For information on how to ask questions, follow this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have rewritten it

Answer (score 1):

From your example I guess you mean similar values instead of similar indices.

Checkout this answer if that's the case:
[Removing Duplicates From Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749158/removing-duplicates-from-dictionary)

Note that Python's dictionaries "values()" method runs in O(n), so the most voted solution will have a O(n^2) complexity, where n is the number of items in the original dictionary.

If that's enough for you, your code will look something like

```
data = {'key1':[1,2,3,4],
     'key2':[1,2,3,4],
     'key3':[1,2,3,4]}

result = {}

for key,value in data.items():
    if value not in result.values():
        result[key] = value
```

At the end, 'result' will have the dictionary without duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

```
for value in data.values():
    del value[index]
```

?

Comment: it doesn't work
ValueError: cannot delete array elements

Comment: Itwill work it the dictionary elements are actually lists, but it looks like you have some other sequence type that does not support item deletion.